# Значення слова "Мольфар" та його походження

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів

Академічний тлумачний словник (СУМ-11) дає таке означення слова [мольфар](http://sum.in.ua/s/moljfar):

> МОЛЬФА́Р, а, чол., діал.
>
> 1. Чарівник. Ще бійка готово вийти з того та сварка, а з мольфаром лиш зачепись... (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 338).
> 2. Злий дух, чорт. Гуцул лякався не тільки пана і жандарма, він жахався на кожному кроці відьми, упиря, мольфара і всякого іншого чортовиння (Петро Козланюк, Сонце.., 1957, 4).

1. То все-ж-таки чорт чи чарівник? І чи будь-який чарівник підходить під це означення?
2. Яке походження цього слова?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Етимологічний словник української мови: В 7 т. / АН УРСР. Ін-т мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні; Редкол. О. С. Мельничук (головний ред.) та ін. — К.: Наук. думка, том 3, 1989 [пише](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.djvu): 
[image]

Та от тільки це не дуже переконливе пояснення, як би це таке італійське слово потрапило до Карпат?..

Comment: Чи є мольфар русинським словом?

Comment: @Artemix - Словник русинсько-руськый (Русинско-русский словарь) [2007, Керча И.] містить слова _молфа, молфарь, молфити_, а Русинсько-Украйинсько-Руський и Русско-Украинско-Русинский словарь [2007, Поп Д.] не містить жодного з них.

Comment: Цікаво, а могло воно від заміни в/ф з'явитися? Тоді буде "молва", "молвар", "молвити" - тобто походити від слова "говорити", а там вже і до "заговорів" недалеко (так само як "врач" від "врати" і т. і.).

Comment: У цій статті (в журналі "Проблеми слов'янознавства" [пдф](http://www.nbuv.gov.ua/old_jrn/Soc_Gum/ps/2007_56/019.pdf)) правда пишуть що зв'язок існує, але у протилежний бік - у бойків на основі мольфара-чаклуна сформувалося слово мольфар-брехун: "за другою із цих моделей
сформовані українські бойківське мольфар – “брехун”, “ошуканець” від мольфар –
“знахар”, “чарівник” [КА]"

Comment: @Artemix - Обидва ці русинські словники містять іще слова _малфа_ «мавпа», та _малфовати_ «кривлятися, мавпувати». Може вони якось пов’язані із словом «молфар»?